# How to filter values in columns of df that contains all substring in passed list in Pandas DataFrame Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Any suggestion how to stay only values that contains all substring that in list for any column?:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
    [1, 'foollish', 'molish'], 
    [2, 'barnylishon', 'chacha'], 
    [3, 'bazon', 'gazon'],
    ], 
    columns=['id', 'value_1', 'value_2'])

print (df)
    
search_list = ['a','on']

print ("Desire result for value_1 column:")

df_desire_result = pd.DataFrame(
    [
    [1, 'barnylishon', 'chacha'], 
    [2, 'bazon', 'gazon'], 
    ], 
    columns=['id', 'value_1', 'value_2'])

print (df_desire_result)
```

Comment: What if a row contained `['abcon', 'xyz']` and another one `['abc', 'abc']`. Which one(s) would you keep?

Comment: List can contain any elements that contains any numbers of characters, and can be repeating, so if ['abc', 'abc'] then in example case df will be empty. But if list will be ['ish', 'ish', 'o'] then df will contain series in value_1 ['foollish', barnylishon'] because they both contains 'ish' and 'o'

Comment: So i make search = set(['ish','ish','o']) and your example work perfectly with repeating elements also, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this statement *that contains all substring that in list for any column?* : I figure that if **any** column in a row has **all** the substrings in the `search_list` then retain that row and drop remaining rows.

Then IIUC:

```
cols = df.columns.drop('id').tolist()
m = df[cols].apply(lambda x: all([any(x.str.contains(s)) for s in search_list]), axis=1)
out = df[m]
```

print(out):

```
   id      value_1 value_2
1   2  barnylishon  chacha
2   3        bazon   gazon
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this checks that all values in a row contain one substring? I had understood the other way around: that all substrings in the list are present at least one time in each matching row.

Comment: @mozway I updated answer to reflect my understanding of the question and then the answer according to that.

Comment: @Константин Прудников  please try second method I posted in the answer. That should be more accurate and faster. and let me know. thanks.

Comment: This work perfect and more clear, thanks bro

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
# craft regex pattern
import re
pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, search_list))
# 'a|on'

out = df.loc[(df
   # extract words from all cells
   .filter(like='value')
   .stack()
   .str.extractall(fr'({pattern})')[0]
   # ensure that each word is present at least once per row
   .groupby(level=0).nunique()
   .eq(len(search_list))
   .reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
 )]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   id      value_1 value_2
1   2  barnylishon  chacha
2   3        bazon   gazon
```